# Erro ao criar banco sqlite a partir da apk instalada

Tags: android, sqlite

Utilizei num projeto um banco de dados .sqlite já populado. Importei o bd para a pasta assets e implementei o código para criação e acesso ao banco. Executei o projeto e tudo funcionou ok no emulador e no celular diretamente. O problema é que quando vou gerar a apk assinada para enviar para outras pessoas a aplicação não cria o banco. O apk é gerado normalmente e o app também é instalado no dispositivo, porém na activity que teria q fazer a execução e consulta no banco acontece um erro, que implementei no código com um toast, acusando que não foi possível criar o banco de dados. Não consigo compreender o porque de tudo funcionar ok quando compilo no emulador ou diretamente no celular, mas quando instalo a partir da apk não funcionar a parte do banco.

Alguém teria uma ideia do porque disso acontecer?! 
Obrigado!

Obs.: Eu não consigo ver log de erro pois estou gerando o apk, instalando no dispositivo e executando. Não executo o run no AndroidStudio, pois como eu disse quando é feito o run do projeto no emulador ou dispositivo diretamente não acontece erro, porém quando instalo o app a partir da apk separadamente no dispositivo, o banco de dados não cria. Existe alguma forma de ver log de erro quando o app é instalado e rodado desta forma separada do AndroidStudio?

O erro que dá a mensagem toast "Copy data error" que acusa que o banco não foi criado está neste trecho do código:

```
        //Check exists database
    File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o código do método `copyDatabase()`.

Comment: seria o caso de voce pegar esses dados e colocar eles em um arquivo ".scv" na pasta "res/raw" por exemplo e criar o database em branco pelo método e depois popular ele com os dados desse arquivo ".csv", comigo aconteceu algo parecido e como a massa de dados era relativamente pequena eu solucionei dessa forma.